# How to typedef a template class with a pointer to a member variable

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Suppose I have the following template class

```
template <typename T_Type, typename T_Class, T_Type T_Class::*ptr>
class Foo
{
    using this_type = Foo<T_Type, T_Class, /* ??? */>;
};
```

how do I declare a `this_type` typedef for the class?

Comment: Doesn't `Foo<T_Type, T_Class, ptr>` work? Also, you can just say `using this_type = Foo;` if that's all you need.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR thanks, that works - I tried `using ptr_type = ptr;` and when the compiler complained that the template parameter cannot be used as a type, I assumed (obviously incorrectly) that `Foo<T_Type, T_Class, ptr>` wouldn't work either.

If you put that down as an answer, I'll checkmark it

Comment: @Samaursa *"I tried `using ptr_type = ptr;"`* -- what was this supposed to accomplish? A variable is not a type. Did you intend to make `ptr_type` an alias for the *type of* `ptr`, something more like `using ptr_type = decltype(ptr);` or `using ptr_type = T_Type T_Class::*`? *(Note: I have not run either of those through a compiler to double-check the syntax.)*

Comment: @JaMiT yes, I realised after the compiler error that I am trying to `typedef` a variable - I then should've thought of exactly what Fatih pointed out. It's obvious if I type `using intVec = std::vector<int>;` but it wasn't immediately obvious with many templates swimming around in code :) - regardless, `decltype(ptr)` should indeed work. Your second suggestion is something I haven't thought of before, will try it out.

Comment: Looks like both work: https://godbolt.org/z/vT9d44xeG - learned multiple new things here, thanks everyone :)